# Rails application view isn't displaying what i want

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm probably doing something really stupid but i'm unsure what i'm doing wrong.
I'm making a counter that sees how many times the user has been on the index page in their current session.

The following is in a store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController

 def increment_counter
 if session[:counter].nil?
   session[:counter] = 0
 end
   session[:counter] += 1
 end  

  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
    @counter = increment_counter
    @counter_msg = "You've visited this page #{pluralize(@counter, "time")}"

  end
end
```

And the following here is in application.html.erb layout view.

```
<%= @counter_msg %>
```

Of course with other code but that seems irrelevant for now.

Nothing at all is displayed from @counter_msg

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I have used the suggestions but the counter just displays 0 now and doesn't increment whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

pluralize is a helper method. You must use the line bellow in application.html.erb

```
<%= "You've visited this page #{pluralize(@counter, "time")}" %>
```

or, include helper in your controller:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like you are calling method in wrong place, if you want to show `@counter_msg` then it should be defined inside **application controller** first include helper

`include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`

into **controller** 
 also, the current code is telling you can use your variable inside **store** `index` page.

Answer (score 0):

The pluralize method is a view helper and should be called from inside the view. Also views are exactly designed for this purpose so a display string should be in the view anyway.

```
<%= "You've visited this page #{pluralize(@counter, "time")}" %>
```

Delete the @counter_msg line from the controller.